# Cannot start GDBserver using a serial connection

Tags: embedded-linux, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I'm running a small test program on an embedded Linux target (a Freescale i.MX25), which I'd like to debug using GDB. I connect to the system using an FTDI USB-RS232 cable through am Ubuntu VM. GDBserver is installed on the target. I do not have Ethernet or USB support on the target, so I'm trying to use GDB over serial.

When I log into the target using Minicom, I get:

```
login[1691]: root login on 'ttymxc0'
```

which I presume means that the console is using `ttymxc0`. Then, I try to start GDBserver listening for connections from the VM to the `test` program, residing in `/home`:

```
$ cd /home
$ gdbserver /dev/ttymxc0 test
```

which gives the output (repeatedly):

```
Remote debugging using /dev/ttymxc0
readchar: Socket operation on non-socket
Remote side has terminated connection. GDBserver will reopen the connection
```

Is this an error in the way I'm trying to use GDBserver, or something else? Is there another way to debug the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use ttymxc0 for two things at the same time (serial console and serial gdb). Disable the getty on that serial line and replace it by the gdbserver.

Comment: Ok, how do I do this? The console is my only way into the processor during runtime, so I guess if I disable the console I then won't be able to reassign `ttymxc0` to GDBserver..?

Comment: A getty for a serial line is typically started via init. So how to replace the start up of getty with the gdbserver depends on your specific init system. Can you reflash the target with a modified init config?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am able to reflash the target. Does this mean I would sacrifice the console for the entirety of a session and have to reflash (which takes an hour) to re-enable the console? What procedure would I have to script?